# Progressive Loading of Large PDF document (Linearized) in browser

Tags: javascript, pdf, servlets, pdf.js

We have a requirement to show the initial page(s) of a PDF while the rest of the document gets loaded in the background.

Our data flow is as follows:

```
Client Browser<->IBM HTTP Server (JSP/Servlet based application)<->Spring Boot (Restful web service)<->IBM Filenet P8
```

Currently, for a 15 mb document, it takes around 10-12 secs for the entire document to render in the browser. We need to reduce the time taken by progressively loading the document.

We tried the suggested way of using `PDF.js` observed the Range Requests going from browser to server but the document is not getting rendered. In Chrome it results in an error message-invalid PDF structure. In Firefox it is going into an infinite loop.

Need help with the requirement in terms of technical solutions.

Comment: *Range Requests* only make sense if the same url always returns an identical result (at least in the short run). Servlets on the other hand tend to return results generated just-in-time which in case of numerous file formats results in differences *at least* in creation and/or manipulation timestamp metadata but probably also in the whole structure. Thus, a pdf requested in multiple range requests may result in a patchwork of pdf pieces that don't match, i.e. an invalid pdf.

Comment: Thanks for the response, so does replacing servlet with a REST api resolve the issue for me?

Comment: *"does replacing servlet with a REST api resolve the issue"* - I don't understand; a REST API may well be implemented by means of servlets, so you probably replace servlets by servlets which probably wouldn't change a thing. All I intended to propose is that you check whether multiple requests of the same URL in your construct get responses based on the identical PDF (not merely one looking the same in a PDF viewer). If they don't, your construct is not appropriate for range requests.

Comment: ok if I understand correctly,  calls to the URL multiple times requesting for a specific range of bytes every time should result in the byte chunks being identical. If they are not then my construct is not appropriate. So, the question here is how to make my construct appropriate? is there a way to expose a URL which always returns an identical result?